# What will be the SQL for below statment

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE USER_LOGIN (
    LOGIN_DATE DATE,
    LOGIN_COUNT INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO USER_LOGIN VALUES
    ('2021-04-01', 100),
    ('2021-04-02', 150),
    ('2021-04-03', 200),
    ('2021-04-04', 50);
```

OutPut ->

```
LOGIN_DATE  LOGIN_COUNT
2021-04-01  100
2021-04-02  250
2021-04-03  450
2021-04-04  500
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `SUM` as an analytic function here to generate the rolling sum:

```sql
SELECT LOGIN_DATE, SUM(LOGIN_COUNT) OVER (ORDER BY LOGIN_DATE) LOGIN_COUNT
FROM USER_LOGIN
ORDER BY LOGIN_DATE;
```

Comment: Please, if you are going to answer poorly written questions at least edit them to make them useful for other people. There's no point in providing an answer to a question that nobody else will ever find